# Angular title routing translation

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I have a question.
First of all, I am using ngx translate, but I don't read from the.json file.
I get the Locaization from the database..
Now what I want is that in my router, I create a title for the route. 
I want to translate it based on the current language.
I have read some articles, and they used resolver.
Is this the best or is there another way? or there is something better ?

Comment: please provide some example code, and possibly a https://stackblitz.com example